# Combining eq, parent and index seems not to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have this part of a table:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <input type="text" name="value[]" class="value" />
   </td>
   <td>
      <input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="quantity" />
   </td>
</tr>
```

So, every time I type something on a specific .quantity (I have a lot of `<tr>`'s, I've cloned them) I need the result of "(.value * .quantity)" of each `<tr>`, and then, sum all the results of this `<tr>`'s. Sorry about the English, please le me know if you didn't understand something.

What I've tried so far:

```
 totalRow = 0;

$(document).on('input', "[name='quantity[]']", function totalQuantity() {

    rows = $('.table tbody tr').length;

    totalResult = 0;

    for (var n = 0; n < rows; ++ n){
        totalRow = 0;
        quantity = 0;
        value = 0;
        quantity = $('.quantity').eq($($('.quantity')).parent().parent().index(n)).val();
        value = $('.value').eq($($('.value')).parent().parent().index(n)).val();

        totalRow = quantity * value;
        totalResult = totalResult + totalRow;
    }

    $('#totalQuantity').html(totalResult);
});
```

But this isn't working. The sum lost itself, seems that the indexes are wrong, maybe I'm using parent() wrong. I don't know. Can you guys help me?

**Edit 1:** Print with example
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather then use indexing on elements, use `find()` within each row to find its amount and quantity. Note: `$(selector, this)`is a shortcut for `$(this).find(selector)` :

e.g.

```
$(document).on('input', "[name='quantity[]']", function () {
    var $rows = $('.table tbody tr');
    var totalResult = 0;
    $rows.each(function(){
        var quantity = $('.quantity', this).val();
        var value = $('.value', this).val();
        var totalRow = quantity * value;
        totalResult += totalResult;
    });

    $('#totalQuantity').html(totalResult);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `.map()` , `Array.prototype.reduce()`

```js
$(document).on('input', "[name='quantity[]']", function totalQuantity() {

   // var sum = $(this).val() * $(this).closest("tr").find(".value").val()
  var sum = $(".quantity").map(function(i, el) {
    return el.value * $(this).closest("tr").find(".value").val()
  
  }).get().reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b
  });

   $("#totalQuantity").html(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="value[]" class="value" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="quantity" />
      </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="value[]" class="value" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="quantity" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="totalQuantity"></div>
```